# Kernel Memory in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have been trying to understand how memory is managed in linux kernel.

As per the `Linux Device Drivers` book, the whole of `Physical RAM` is divided into `Pages`. I am assuming that `PageSize=4096 bytes` for better understanding here. Also, it is the kernel that maintains the page table for all the pages that represent actual memory in RAM.

On x86 system the `total physical RAM addressable by CPU is 4GB` ( leave `PAE(Physical Address Extension` out of it for now ).

Now this, `4GB` of address space is divided as per the following:

```
0-3GB   User Address Space
3GB-4GB Kernel Address Space
```

Therefore, during the execution of a process any valid addresses that the process can access/generate without being in kernel mode is `0-3GB`.

Since this is a virtual address space of a process, so the physical memory(RAM) has to be accessed via some translation mechanism. `Page Tables` do that translation for the process. As the process is loaded into memory, kernel allocates the pages from its array of page tables and as and when needed the pages are allocated to this process. Correct me if I my understanding is wrong.

The problem that I am facing is understanding how kernel manages its `address space of 1GB`.

I read somewhere that the kernel memory of 1GB is divided into:

```
Low Memory (896MB)
High Memory (128MB)
```

So the first `896MB` of memory is called `kernel logical address` and it has `somewhat`( in some cases an offset may be added) 1:1 mapping to `Physical Address` i.e. it does not require `page table translation`.

For the other `128MB`, it is said to be called `High Memory` and it defines the `Kernel Virtual address` and maintains rest of the `Physical Memory(RAM)`.

What I am struggling to understand is that if the system is x86(32-bit), the maximum address that a CPU can generate is within `0-4GB`, so what's the need for `High Memory` ?

Also, assume that I have a `PCI bus` on same system that has a `memory`(Static RAM) connected to it. The size of the `Static RAM` is about `3MB`. Will this `3MB` be part of the `0-4GB` of address space?

Comment: Low memory is for the linux kernel to load itself in, initialize the vector table, drivers, memory manager/scheduler etc. It is not like the DOS days where there was High Memory (HIMEM). Ultimately, the Kernel reside in the first 1GB region. Untouchable to userspace.

Comment: I understand that part. To be more specific, when kernel is executing can we generate addresses more than 4GB on x86 system ? Since that is the limit on the CPU, I would assume 'No'. Correct me if I am wrong. Now, if there can not be addresses more than 4GB, what's the point of `High Memory` then ?

Comment: On 32bit x86 cpu platform, absolute max is 4GB. So no, that is not possible. To get more than 4GB, move to x64 cpu.

Comment: Man, cmon. Say there are only 2 processes running, each eating 1GB. This leaves 2GB of free RAM in total. But the kernel can only use 1GB of the virtual address space. So, how to allow the kernel to use more than 1GB of memory in total? Designate an area of the address space where you map and unmap physical pages as needed. And that's High Memory.

Comment: If the address space is fixed to 1GB, then whats the use of mapping/unmapping physical pages ? The address space is never going to increase.

Comment: You map and unmap *different* physical pages to the same small area. Let's take a toy example with high memory area being only wide enough for one page. If for each physical page you map it into the area and unmap, you effectively managed to iterate through the entire memory in the kernel, despite the address space usable by the kernel being only 1GB.

Comment: Assume that the `High Memory` area is around 128MB. With each physical page being 4KB in size, the total Kernel Virtual Address pages(in High Mem area) will be 128MB/4KB, which is 32KB. so you are telling me that I can allocate pages in this `High Memory` area having same virtual address page but different physical pages? And in what situations would same virtual address be required to be mapped to different Physical pages ?

Comment: I already said. A kernel with only 1GB of virtual address space can, by definition, only address 1GB of physical memory at any given time. So a certain number of pages is mapped. But you want to access more. But in order do that, you have to map a page. But since the whole address space is already used, you have to unmap something. And there goes high memory - an area designated to use in such circumstances. Also I don't follow the 128MB/4KB = 32KB bit. I presume you mean 128MB/4Kb= 32678 *pages* which can be mapped at a time in there.

Comment: _I read somewhere that the kernel memory of 1GB is divided into: …_ - Instead of _somewhere_, you should name where exactly you read it, so that we can verify the source and don't try to explain obsolete information.